# A question about relatively prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b$ be positive integers. Prove there is a positive integer n such that $gcd(a+n,b)=1$.

I have tried many ways but still get so solutions, could somebody give me some hints. Many thanks.

Comment: Set $n=r\cdot b\pm 1-a$, choose $r$ such that $n>0$

Comment: Another choice: pick a prime $p > a, b$ and set $n = p - a$

Comment: How is this abstract algebra?

Answer (score 1):

My take on this is that the key here is to realize that we have exceptional latitude in choosing $n$, as long as $q \not\mid (a + n)$ for any prime $q$ such that $q \mid b$.  So if $p_1 < p_2 < . . . p_N$ are the primes dividing $b$, simply choose a prime $p > \max \{a, p_N\}$ and set $n = p - a$.  Then $p = a + n$ and $\gcd (a + n, b) = \gcd (p, b) = 1$, since $b$ and $p = a + n$ have no prime factors in common.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Like user115654 said in his comment, which I didn't see until after I posted! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Can you show that $$\gcd(bk + 1, b) = 1$$ for all integers $k$? Do you see how to use this?